# Управление асинхронной функцией

Tags: javascript, node.js

У меня вопрос. Можно ли как то сделать, что при запуске асинхронной функции, если уже есть запущенная асинхронная функция с такими же аргументами, её не запускать.

Answer (score 1):

создайте в общей области видимости переменную `isRuning = false`, при старте асинхронной функции присвойте ей значение `true` и отталкивайтесь от неё)).

> UPDATE

не заметил в вопросе, что еще и аргументы надо учитывать. в комментариях `@vsemozhebuty` предложил достойный вариант

Comment: Если нужно проверять аргументы, эту переменную можно сделать объектом или типом Map и вставлять туда подобные флаги по ключам, содержащим аргументы.

Comment: @vsemozhebuty, оо чёрт, я как-то упустил в вопросе, что и аргументы надо учитывать